# SQL Injections - Web for Pentester (Pentesterlab)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

I am attending a free online course at Pentesterlab and today I am getting comfortable with SQL Injections.
However I don't get the instructions and as it could be a huge (technical) difference I would want to know how it works.

The stuff I am talking about: 
https://www.pentesterlab.com/exercises/web_for_pentester/course 
Please scroll down more than the half to "SQL Injections" --> "Example 1".

In the example we found out, that the (My)SQL-Table should work like this pattern:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='[INPUT]';
```

As I understand this, all I am providing through the URL is the "INPUT", the quotes (') before and after the input, and the semicolon (;) is added by SQL automatically.

However, the instruction says:

> ?name=root' and '1'='1: the quote in the initial query will close the
>   one at the end of our injection.

I don't get it. I thought the quote (') after root ends the first part, but there's still the other part '1'='1 , isn't it?
Maybe it's a misunderstanding of the language, however I am not sure if I understood it .

Imo the SQL should look like this (for example 1, first "code"):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name=' root' and '1'='1 ';
```

At the second try at Example 1 it's getting stranger:

> ?name=root' and '1'='1' # (don't forget to encode #): the quote in the initial query will be commented out.

Wait what? I thought the quote provided by SQL automatically gets commented out.

Imo the SQL should look like this (for example 1, second "code"):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name=' root' and '1'='1' # ';
```

Hope someone can clear it out, if I understand it right and it's just to hard for me explained or if I am messing up something.

Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 1):

Mysql does not addanything automatically to your query. If you are not providing a single quote, then it will not be there. Period.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='[INPUT]';
```

The application will contain the above sql statement template in its own code and will substitute the parameter received from the user in place of the `[INPUT]` placeholder.

If you provide a single name, as you are supposed to, then the query executed will be:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='root';
```

However, if you provide `root' and '1'='1` as an input, then the sql code being executed will be

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='root' and '1'='1';
```

The single quote before `root` and after the 2nd `1` are part of the sql statement template within the application.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read the course, so let's assume the logic will check the user exists in database only.

Original SQL

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = 'admin'
(1 row affected)
```

By SQL injection, you can input something after that to make this SQL always return records

> by input user name as [root' and '1' = '1]

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = 'root' and '1' = '1'
(20 rows affected)
```

However, let's assume this SQL will also check the password

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = 'admin' and pwd = 'abc'
(1 row affected)
```

> by input user name as [root' and '1' = '1]

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = 'root' and '1' = '1' and pwd = 'invalid'
(0 row affected)
```

We need to bypass the password, what need to do is comment out the rest of SQL

> by input user name as [root' and '1' = '1'#]

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = 'root' and '1' = '1'#' and pwd = 'abc'
(20 rows affected)
```

With this SQL, it will comment out the password checking, and it will grant access even you don't have the correct user name and password